# How do I show that $\int_\mathbb{R} \sigma \exp(-\frac{\sigma^2 \xi^2}{2})f(\xi)d\xi\to c<\infty$ as $\sigma\to\infty$?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Let $f$ be a bounded probability density function. How do I show that $\int_\mathbb{R} \sigma \exp(-\frac{\sigma^2 \xi^2}{2})f(\xi)d\xi\to c<\infty$ as $\sigma\to\infty$?

I was thinking of doing dominated convergence theorem, but this doesn't work here. Could anyone give me any direction?

Comment: So I was thinking that $\sigma \exp(-\frac{\sigma^2\xi^2}{2})$ is bounded and $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(\xi)d\xi=1$ by definition, so by the dominated convergence theorem, I get integral converging to zero. But this does sound very wrong when I think about the fact that integrand is all positive:( It might be that $\sigma \exp(-\frac{\sigma^2\xi^2}{2})$ is not bounded, yeah

Comment: Why is my question closed?

Comment: For what it's worth, I am pretty sure that what you're trying to prove is false in general. It is true if you assume e.g. that $f$ is continuous, using a change of variable (as in angryavian's answer) and the dominated convergence theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $f(\xi)$ is bounded and all terms are positive in the integral. Can you find an upper bound for the integrand?

Let us assume $f(\xi)\leq \dfrac{c}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$.

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sigma\exp\left[-\dfrac{\sigma^2\xi^2}{2}\right]f(\xi)d\xi\leq \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sigma\exp\left[-\dfrac{\sigma^2\xi^2}{2}\right]\dfrac{c}{\sqrt{2\pi}}d\xi$$
$$=\sigma\dfrac{c}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left[-\dfrac{\sigma^2\xi^2}{2}\right]d\xi$$

Note, that the upper bound of the integral is gaussian integral. And we have

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left[-\dfrac{\sigma^2\xi^2}{2}\right]d\xi = \dfrac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{|\sigma|}.$$

Hence, we obtain

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sigma\exp\left[-\dfrac{\sigma^2\xi^2}{2}\right]f(\xi)d\xi\leq\sigma\dfrac{c}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\dfrac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{|\sigma|}=c.$$

Comment: I think this shows that the integral is $\le c$ for any $\sigma$, but not that it necessarily converges to some constant as $\sigma \to \infty$.

Comment: @angryavian We are integrating a positive expression, which implies that the value of the integral is monotonically increasing. As the integral is bounded from above I would assume that it converges. Or is my reasoning incorrect?

Comment: I'm not sure where you have shown that the value of the integral is increasing as $\sigma$ increases.

Comment: I mean that the integral $\int_{-\infty}^x ... d\xi$ is increasing in $x$. My statement is independet of $\sigma$.

Comment: The question is asking how to show $\lim_{\sigma\to \infty} g(\sigma) = c < \infty$ where $g(\sigma) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \sigma e^{-\sigma^2 \xi^2/2} f(\xi) \, d\xi$. I think your answer only shows $g(\sigma) \le c$ for all $\sigma > 0$.

Comment: I think the point being made here is that the limit itself is independent of $\sigma$. You've shown the limit exists by the monotone convergence theorem, but not that it is the same regardless of $\sigma$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I see your point. I thought that I had show convergence because the integral is increasing and the upper bound is constant. Both these statements are independet of $\sigma$. I will have to think about this to finally conclude if my answer is wrong.

Comment: To apply the monotone convergence theorem you need to show $g(\sigma) \le g(\sigma')$ when $\sigma < \sigma'$, not that $\int_{-\infty}^x \cdots d\xi \le \int_{-\infty}^{x'} \cdots d\xi$ when $x < x'$.

Answer (score 1):

With the change of variables $u=\sigma \xi$ we can rewrite your integral as
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-u^2/2} f(u/\sigma) \, du.$$
This integrand is dominated by $e^{-u^2/2} (\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} f(x))$ which is integrable. If you show that the pointwise limit (as $\sigma \to \infty$) of the integrand is zero almost everywhere (except at $u=0$ where the limit is $f(0)$) then you can conclude by applying the dominated convergence theorem.